# Wait for element and return it

Tags: python, selenium

As per [Waits — Selenium Python Bindings 2 documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html), I can wait for e.g. an element to be present and visible (e.g. if it's loaded by an AJAX call) like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

d = selenium.webdriver.<whichever>()
w = WebDriverWait(d,10)

w.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"<xpath>")))
```

However, to work with this element after this, I have to locate it again (duplicating the search parameters) which is very inconvenient. **Since this is a common task, I'm pretty sure `selenium` must have some shortcut that would wait for an element and return it upon success.**

- I've already looked through the aforementioned article and [`WebDriverWait` reference](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=WebDriverWait#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) to no avail.
- There are some locators  -- e.g. [`visibility_of()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=WebDriverWait#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of) -- that accept a `WebElement`. But since the element doesn't exist initially, I cannot make a `WebElement` for it beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [until](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html#until-java.util.function.Function-) function returns the `WebElemwnt` returned from the `Expected_condition`

> The function's return value if the function returned something
>   different from null or false before the timeout expired.

`visibility_of_element_located` uses internally `driver.find_element`. If the search was successful in the declared time out the located `WebElement` will be returned.

```
element = w.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"<xpath>")))
# do something with the element
```

Comment: Oh, I see. It's not actually `until` but the predicate that returns the element. `until` just returns whatever the predicate does. I was experimenting with a custom predicate (e.g. I need multiple conditions), and I wasn't returning the element, so I couldn't see this fact.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Yes, I edited the answer to be more clear about that.

Comment: This was a bit unexpected since a predicate, by definition, is a function that returns a boolean. [Heck, this is not even documented!](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait.until) Looks like I'll be writing yet another pull request...

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Have a look ate the [github docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located) (there is a link to the source code there as well). It states `returns the WebElement once it is located and visible`. You can have a look at Java's [visibilityOfElementLocated source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java), maybe it will make more sense to you.

Comment: Wow, thanks! https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/ should get me going. I couldn't find it, it doesn't come up in Google, only Java docs do -- and they are useless 'cuz the package structure, types, fields, signatures etc are completely different.